# How to use Input placeholder in a right way? Am trying to use transforms to placeholders but it does not work? screenshot is below

Tags: javascript, css, html, sass

How to use Input placeholder in a right way? I am trying to use transforms to placeholders, but it does not work. **css** is below

[image]

Comment: Just fyi, you can post markup on StackOverflow, without taking a screenshot.. can you please do that? :-)

Comment: I dont know how to do that?

Comment: Can you guide how can i do?

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan Just copy the **html** portion and **css** from your code to the question

Comment: Thanks I do it now

Comment: ... and highlight and press CTRL+K on the keyboard

Comment: #coder_slider .get_qoute .qoute_form input[type="text"]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
#coder_slider .get_qoute .qoute_form input[type="text"]:focus::-moz-placeholder,
#coder_slider .get_qoute .qoute_form input[type="text"]:focus::-ms-input-placeholder,
#coder_slider .get_qoute .qoute_form input[type="text"]:focus:-moz-placeholder{

    
}

Comment: Not in the comments... in your post!

Comment: Mate this code not working with comas but when i use this sepraterly it works well

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? Kind of difficult to tell, as you haven't really explained your question / problem..

```
.quote_form input[type=text]{
    font-size: 8px;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.quote_form input[type=text]:focus{
    padding-left: -10px; // to space the placeholder text away from the border 
    padding-top: -5px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

**Note that**: the padding needs to be accounted for when setting your width and height on the `input` field :)

Comment: I hope he wants to show some animation on that placeholder when focusing on to that input

Comment: Yes i want to animate the placeholder on focus with translate

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can trigger css `transition` applying a [pseudo selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes), in your case could be `:focus`.
In this case I use `font-size` for `inputs` in order to increase the size of the `placeholder`.
Please consider adding your HTML and CSS markup so we can provide you a "specific" solution.

An example, click to the input in order to focus:

```css
input[type=text]{
font-size: 8px;
transition: all 0.5s linear;
border:1px solid black;
}
input[type=text]:focus{
padding-left: -50px;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<input class="quote_form" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="placeholder"><br>
<input class="quote_form" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="placeholder">
```